# Categories as well as products not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, category, products, category-products

I'm using magento 1.9.1 on my godaddy windows server and installed the [istudio7](http://themeforest.net/item/istudio-7-premium-responsive-magento-theme/7033892) theme. In the description it says 1.8 is the last supported version. but in responses they say it works on 1.9 and on a later response it's said that they are working on 1.9 support so this is a little confusing.

I followed the instructions they sent me with the download and changed my package name under Configuration > general > design into istudio7 changed colors to my liking and added banner images/favicon/logo etc. This is all working fine.

Then I went on and imported the Default theme settings.

after that I created a custom block for my category and assigned my category and product to this. Deleted the cache and gave it a look on my site, but it isn't showing up in my menu bar and the product isn't being shown in the new products section. Actually the entire section isn't visible at all.

Does anyone have a clue of what I'm doing wrong? I already tried to assign the category to the standard menu block but this didn't change anything.

Comment: did you try this with the default template, does it work then? If it works with default, then you should put your question with their support. If it doesn't then please paste your code snippets. Else no one is able to post a constructive answer.

Comment: @7ochem I tried changing it back to the default template but isn't working on that either. What code snippets do you mean exactly? Sorry this is the first time I'm working with magento so it's all new to me

Comment: This sounds like you havn't configured your categories / products correctly, or else it should work in the default theme. I'd go a step back, configure your categories & products so they show in the default theme, then switch themes.

Comment: @tecjam You where right. I actually created a new root category instead of inside the default category folder.
I'm still left with the problem that it doesn't show on the home page tho. Also is it normal that the site takes ages to load both on front and back end

Comment: @NoSixties: Glad I could be of help. On the homepage you would have to configure your cms front page and insert a widget to show products, or get the category ID of the one you wish top make your store front and go to  "System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages" and enter the following for the "Default web url" option: catalog/category/view/id/10 (where 10 is the id of the category). I'll add all this to a propper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you havn't configured your categories / products correctly, or else it should work in the default theme. I'd go a step back, configure your categories & products so they show in the default theme, then switch themes.

---

Part2:

Normally a homepage will have different widgets showing latest products, imagesliders for promotions  and anything else you want there to make the initial customer impression.

You can either edit your existing front page or create a new one, or use a category as the store front.

On the homepage you would have to configure or edit your cms front page via cms -> pages and insert a widget to show products of a certain category

[image]

eg:

`{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="8" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}`

Or if you wish to make a category your front page, get the category ID of the one you wish top make your store front and go to "System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages" and enter the following for the "Default web url" option: catalog/category/view/id/10 (where 10 is the id of the category).

Comment: alright I checked my widgets and pages and I saw that in my page section there are 2 home pages. the default one and the one that comes with the theme. When selecting the theme one there is code there for the widgets. BUT the widget page is empty so this home page is giving me a 500 error. Do you happen to have any idea how to get my widgets to show.. I already contacted the creaters of the theme yesterday but no response as of yet

Comment: I'd go with the normal homepage or blank new page and add a widget yourself (in the editor it's the 2nd icon > widget type: Catalog new products list) and configure as you wish for testing. When you switch the editor off you can see the actual widget code and/or modify it.

Comment: I will try that for now. ofcourse I would like to have the widgets that came with the site cause there where a bunch of them. But thanks for your help I should be able to get somewhere now

Comment: I guess most bought themes have some preconfigured widgets already via some modules and a homepage that it imports with the code. But since yours is giving you errors, maybe just try one widget from that page after another. to see which one causes the error and contact your themes creators. And in regards to site speed - yes, without compilation, caching and a powerful correctly configured server magento can suck a lot of resources and take long for page loads.

Comment: well I have caching turned of right now for obvious reasons lol. the server should be good cause it's a godaddy installation. they offer it as app. I hope it will be better when I actually release it. in the widget tab currently nothing is being shown there so I guess it has something to do with the theme being 1.8 and my installation being 1.9

Comment: That is strange. In the default install of magento 1.9.1 without any data it shows various widgets to select from.

Comment: Do you happen to know where the widgets would be normally located in the folder structure? Like where would I be able to find them on my ftp

Comment: Just to check, you aren't looking in CMS -> Widgets, are you? That will be empty. What I mean is if you go to CMS -> Pages and edit or create a blank page with the editor enabled, the second icon in the editor icons list is the 'widget insert icon' that will open a dialogue. See here: http://i.imgur.com/VvA7W8x.png

Comment: I figured it out in the end. Certain attributes wherent added yet had to do that manually and the page was showing me errors cause the widgets used those attributes

Comment: Im glad you managed to solve this.